# Return index of a clicked JButton in Java swing

Tags: java, swing, indexing, jbutton

I have the following Java code:
I have a for loop and I'm creating JButtons.
I would like to return the index of the clicked button.
So i use:

```
    JButton jbtn = (JButton) e.getSource();
```

Is there any method that returns the JButton's index?

My code is as follows:

```
for (int button = 0 ; button <= ListofJButtons.size() - 1; button++) {

    ListofJButtons.get(button).addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            System.out.println("I clicked on button !");
            JButton buttonSource = (JButton) e.getSource();
            System.out.println( " sourceButton " + buttonSource.getIndex()); //is there any method like that in Java?
        }
    } );

}//for loop
```

Is it possible to get the Index of the clicked JButton?

thanks

Comment: why? Unrelated: please learn java naming conventions and stick to them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several ways. The simplest would be to do:

```
for (int button = 0 ; button <= ListofJButtons.size() - 1; button++) {
    final int index = button;
    ListofJButtons.get(button).addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            // Because index is final I can access it here and know the index
            System.out.println("I clicked on button "+index+"!");
            JButton buttonSource = (JButton) e.getSource();
            System.out.println( " sourceButton " + buttonSource.getIndex()); //is there any method like that in Java?
        }
    } );
}//for loop
```

The other simplest way would be just to do `ListofJButtons.indexOf(buttonSource)`.

Answer (score 1):

I guess `ListofJButtons` is a `java.util.List`. If so you can use

```
JButton buttonSource = (JButton) e.getSource();
int index = ListofJButtons.indexOf(buttonSource);
```

Answer (score 1):

From ActionEvent you can do getActionCommand or from button you can get the getText or getLabel. Since buttons do not have any property which gives them a index you can't get the index. Index in not defined for them.